# Django rest framework and normalizr

Tags: django-rest-framework, normalizr

```
class A:
  b = foreigneKey(B)


class B:
  pass
```

Django rest framework serializes A instance as

```
{ 
  'id': 1,
  'b': 3
}
```

normalizr (https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) seems to want a format of

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'b': {
    'id': 3
  }
}
```

I could change DRF 's default PrimaryKeyRelatedField's serialization, but I 'm wondering if there's another way?